# What was skekUng's original title?

Tags: dark-crystal, dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

In the Dark Crystal, skekUng is referred to as the Garthim-Master.

However, from Age of Resistance we know that skekTek created the Garthim long after the Great Division.

What was skekUng's title before the creation of the Garthim?

Answer (score 1):

SkekUng's title pre-movie is currently unknown, with his movie-era titles being General (after replacing skekVar in *Age of Resistance*), Garthim-Master (presumably this one would be granted him in Season 2 of *Age of Resistance* now that the Garthim have been created), and eventually Emperor (following the death of skekSo and defeating skekSil in the Trial by Stone).

However, skekUng is the counterpart of [urIm](http://www.darkcrystal.com/encyclopedia_urim.php), the Mystics' Healer, so presumably his title would be urIm's opposite and would involve causing injury instead of repairing it as the Mystic would. SkekZok refers to skekUng as "a great warrior" in *Age of Resistance*; it is possible that skekUng's original title would be martially related as well.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there has been no revelation for what skekUng's title is.  He is absent during Age of Resistance season 1.